# How to display formatted xml string in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc

Anyone please help, this is an example xml string, this string is dynamic

```
string htmlSample = "<Employee><Details Address='xxx' Place='yyy'/></Employee>";
```

I want to print this in div like this format

```
<Employee>
    <Details Address="xxx" Place="yyy" />
</Employee>
```

Using JavaScript how can I achieve this ?

Comment: You want to print the details in div? What do you mean by format? You want the tags to appear as well?

Comment: Hi Rachit Gupta, Thanks for your responce,  div or text area  , format means there you can see the expected result that i had put in my question itself. yes the string i get like a single line but i want to show it like node by node with new lines